# Oracle SQL Triggers - How to read each new row

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to write an AFTER INSERT trigger that looks somewhat like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER database.table_name
  AFTER INSERT
  ON database.table_name
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW_ROW
  FOR EACH ROW 
  
  BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
  
  DECLARE COUNT INTEGER;
       /* code and stuff */
  END
```

The problem I'm having is that this trigger is not looping through the inserts to do what I'm asking it to do.

If 30 new rows are inserted, this trigger will only run on the first row, and then end. How do I get it to run the "code and stuff" on all the newly inserted rows?

Comment: The `FOR EACH ROW` clause should cause that the trigger is fired for each row. Are you sure about the problem? Please show us your code.

Comment: "NOT ATOMIC" is not valid syntax for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code won't compile. Not only is `NOT ATOMIC` not valid in Oracle, but you have the order of `DECLARE`, `BEGIN`, and `END` wrong in the body of the trigger, and the proposed trigger name would duplicate the name of the table on which the trigger is (trying to be) defined.

Perhaps something like the following would be more likely to succeed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER database.table_name_AI
  AFTER INSERT
  ON database.table_name
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW_ROW
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
  nCOUNT INTEGER;
BEGIN
  NULL;  /* code and stuff */
END database.table_name_AI;
```

[See this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c74b61c1b618fea1dfb7a7becb2e9f5)